# OpenELEC, Transmission not installed

Tags: transmission, xbmc

In official doc and forum could not find fresh info. Have anyone succeeded to install transmission on OpenELEC 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 different transmission addons for XBMC:

- The **server** add-on: you must install it in order to run transmission on your XBCM/OpenELEC machine.
- The **client** add-on: is for downloading and managing torrents from the XBMC interface. You do not have to install it in order to be able to download torrents.

To get them on OpenELEC 3.0:

**Server Add-on** -
System → Setting → Add-ons → Get Add-ons → All Add-ons → Services → transmission

**Client Add-on** - Programs → Get More → Transmission

Instead of using the client Add-on you can use the web-interface by browsing to `http://[openelecIP]:9091` from any computer on the same network.

To find out the IP of your XBMC navigate to System → System Info → Network

Answer (score 13):

On `OpenELEC 3.2`, the server Add-On has been moved to a new Unofficial Add-on Repo (see [this](http://openelec.tv/news/20-project/102-new-unofficial-addon-repo)).

To get that add-on, it is thus necessary to:

1) Install the new repo (not included by default in `OpenELEC`) by downloading it from [here](http://unofficial.addon.pro).

2) Follow the steps described by amirnissim remembering to look for the service in the unofficial repo.

Answer (score 3):

For Openelec 4.0, you don't need to download a zip file anymore.

1. Enable Unofficial repo: settings -> Add-ons -> get Add-ons -> All Add-ons -> Add-on repository -> Unofficial OpenELEC ... (Just click on it, it will then be enabled)
2. Enable Transmission Service: Settings -> Add-ons -> get Add-ons -> All Add-ons -> Services -> Transmission
3. Install client: System -> Settings -> Add-ons -> Get Add-ons -> All Add-ons -> Transmission

Comment: What can one do when "clicking on it" does nothing at all?

Comment: I know it is a strange behavior, but I think something is activated in background when you have clicked on it.

Comment: Found it out: I had to go via add ons -> get add ons -> open elec repo -> unofficial repo to get it to install.

Comment: After I enabled the Unofficial repository, it was empty. I had to restart Openelec to find and install the add-on.

Answer (score 1):

yes, I use transmission on my dedicated openelec box.

do not install from terminal. since openelec is embedded, transmission has to be compiled specifically for openelec.

if you install transmission through >>programs >> get more.. >> transmission
you will just get the user interface,.. which you will still need the server installed

to install transmission server for openelec navigate to >> settings >> add-ons >> openelec mediacenter os add-ons >> services >> transmission

you can then configure the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with OpenElec 5.x and trying to follow Snook steps I can`t find Transmission under: Settings -> Add-ons -> get Add-ons -> All Add-ons -> Services -> Transmission.

I've already tried rebooting raspberry/OpenElec, turning on/off raspberry/OpenElec after install Unofficial OpenELEC but it never is shown.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to update the repositories, I can't remember where the option is exactly but it's the missing step.

Comment: OK! I solved the problem just unistalling/installing Transmission client.